# Do Windows Applications usually have a console for StdIn, StdOut and StdErr

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, freepascal, lazarus

I ran into the following issue using Pascal/FPC/Lazarus, but I think it is universal to all Windows .exe files, regardless of the IDE/compiler they are created with:

I created a Windows GUI application and wanted to display some debugging infos in a simple text console. Usually in a Pascal console application Write and WriteLn are used to write to a console/StdOut, but without additional measures in the project configuration this crashes because in a GUI exe (at least if created with Lazarus) a console window does not exist, I get a "file not open" exception.

There are multiple ways in Lazarus (centered around controlling the -WG switch during the build process) to get a console attached "write /writeln" can write text to, this is not the question. My question is, whether support for a console device (StdIn, StdOut, StdErr) is a Windows feature, which is part of the Windows Runtime, probably controlled by some metadata embedded in the exe, which in turn is controlled by this -WG switch, or whether it is a feature of a runtime environment added by a specific development environment, in this case by the Lazarus IDE or a runtime coming with the underlying FPC compiler.

Thnx!

Comment: It depends on which subsystem the executable targets, either console subsystem or gui subsystem. Typically executables that show windowed UI target the latter and don't have stdin, stdout, stderr.

Comment: There is that -WG compiler switch in FPC, which, when creating a GUI application, controls whether an additional console with stdOut attached is created, which is a conveninent way to display debugging/tracking infos. I wonder whether this is a Windows feature applying to all WIndows GUI applications, or a FPC goodie applying to Windows applications created with Lazarus/FPC only.

Comment: That isn't what -WG does as I read the docs. That specifies that the executable will target GUI subsystem. Windows is very different from *nix in this way. If you want to produce debugging info, then you are better using a logging library.

Comment: Confusing! This would mean that I target "a different subsystem"? This seems not to be the case, since my GUI runs fine with and without -WG. It's only that I get an additional text console, if I remove -WG.

Comment: As @Marco says, Lazarus is calling `AllocConsole` for you which is where the console comes from. As a rule, a GUI app should not do this. Use a logging library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consoles are generally not used for Windows GUI apps, though you can afaik instantiate some with allocconsole manually. Very early versions of Lazarus did this.

As David says, in general on Windows Outputdebugstring() is used or a logging library.

---

Technical details:  afaik all windows processes (so also console) must actively activate the console, a task typically done by the runtime. The -WG switch suppresses this by setting a special IsConsole boolean variable to false.

The console io initialization is in rtl/win/syswin.inc  procedure SysInitStdIO around line 515.

In there you can see that if not IsConsole a dummy file description is made (assignerror), and errors are redirected to message boxes(and might pass by GUI users unnoticed).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but it doesn't quite match my question. I thought a while that a GUI apllication and a console application are exclusive options, you target your application to one of those when you create it. I was baffled whan I learned about this -WG switch recently, which is by default set if I choose to create a GUI application. If I remove it, I get GUI *and* console. The same happens if I add {$Apptype Console} to a GUI application. I expected to lose the GUI, but didn't, instead I got a perfectly working additional console in addition to the GUI.

Comment: I added some details to my post. What you describe is the old situation, but it was later changed to better conform with general Windows GUI programs, and to have popups if something happens. Some programs also assign dummy descriptors with a parameter to log it all to file.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort On Windows I don't runtimes need to "activate" a console. If the PE file says that the executable targets console subsystem then the loader makes sure there is a console. Either by attaching to console of parent process, or making a new console.

Comment: Then maybe our way is a workaround to use one RTL. Maybe this should be revisited now we have an own linker.

Comment: So, just to be sure I put all your useful answers together - the correct answer to my original question would be, that this dual-window behaviour (1 GUI, 1 console) is a goodie of the Lazarus/FPC runtime and not something common to all programs running under Windows?

Comment: Possible yes, probably rooted in old Lazarus times, when the windows version of Lazarus used GTK(1), and was quite keep on doing verbal diarrhoea to the console.

Comment: I looked around, and while Lazarus/FPC also sets the PE flags for console/gui, it also changes the entry point from _WinMainCRTStartup (GUI) to  _MainCRTStartup (console). It is this latter change that changes the variable that the EXE tests. Some of this complexity might also be from link compatibility to cygwin libraries in the early years.